# Detecting History Change using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Here is what I would do in JavaScript.  Is there any way to do it in php?
I am working on a project that needs this functionality but cannot use JavaScript.

```
setInterval ( "checkHistory()", 1000 );

function checkHistory() {
   if (oldHistLength != history.length) {
      removegateway();
      oldHistLength = history.length;
   }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to read the browser history from the server side?

Comment: why not to use js? you could just send the data to php in an ajax request.

Comment: @ChristopherKenney I think Peggy is saying he cant use JavaScript altogether. Am I right?

Comment: @ChristopherKenney  if js is disabled on visitors browser will ajax request work?

Comment: You would need to implement that yourself pushing requested urls onto either a session variable or storing them in the cookies or in the database.

Comment: Peggy you can answer that question `ajax = asynchronous JavaScript and XML `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to say that it's not possible to do that using PHP. Your only option is to use JavaScript somewhere.

You can however achieve what I believe you're trying to do with another technique - PHP Sessions and Request URIs.

This involves storing the user's accessed URLs into a variable (or you could use MySQL) which can be referenced anywhere on the website within that current session.

Here's an (untested) example:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Retrieve/create the current list
if( isset($_SESSION['history']) ) {
    $history = $_SESSION['history'];
} else {
    $history = new array();
}

// Add the current URL to the history array
array_push($history, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// Do anything else you want to here

// Store the array again
$_SESSION['history'] = $history;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you can keep an array containing the values of $_SERVER['php_self'], `serialize()` it, and store it in a session variable. This may not be sufficient for what you are trying to do though. I'm not sure what `removegateway()` does, but is this code attempting to prevent the back button from being used?

If you prevent the pages from being cached, you might be able to compare the second to the last value in your array to the current page, and if they match, you detected a back button. This would only be possible if there's no way to go back to the previous page on the front end.

Preventing the back button is generally considered a Bad Thing, so it might be better to reconsider the way you are doing things and come up with a better solution.